# indexing numpy array with logical operator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 2d numpy array, for instance as:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.zeros( (500,2) )

a1[:,0]=np.arange(0,500)
a1[:,1]=np.arange(0.5,1000,2)
# could be also read from txt
```

then I want to select the indexes corresponding to a slice that matches a criteria such as all the value a1[:,1] included in the range (l1,l2):

```
l1=20.0; l2=900.0; #as example
```

I'd like to do in a condensed expression. However, neither:

```
np.where(a1[:,1]>l1 and a1[:,1]<l2)
```

(it gives ValueError and it suggests to use np.all, which it is not clear to me in such a case); neither:

```
np.intersect1d(np.where(a1[:,1]>l1),np.where(a1[:,1]<l2))
```

is working (it gives unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray')

My idea is then to use these indexes to map another array of size (500,n).

Is there any reasonable way to select indexes in such way? Or: is it necessary to use some mask in such case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work

```
np.where((a1[:,1]>l1) & (a1[:,1]<l2))
```

or

```
np.where(np.logical_and(a1[:,1]>l1, a1[:,1]<l2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.zeros( (500,2) )
a1[:,0]=np.arange(0,500)
a1[:,1]=np.arange(0.5,1000,2)
c=(a1[:,1]>l1)*(a1[:,1]<l2) # boolean array, true if the item at that position is ok according to the criteria stated, false otherwise 
print a1[c] # prints all the points in a1 that correspond to the criteria
```

afterwards you can than just select from your new array that you make, the points that you need (assuming your new array has dimensions (500,n)) , by doing

```
print newarray[c,:]
```

Comment: It would be preferable to use np.logical_and(), rather than the multiplication. Afaik they will give identical results and identical performance under all relevant circumstances, but it makes the structure of the code more explicit.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn not exactly certain what you mean by "more explicit", but to me the multiplication is more readable, though thats maybe due to my maths background, and that for a programmer the "np.logical_and" is more readable?

Comment: I also have a maths background; from that perspective, the type of the > operator is a bool, so it makes sense to use a logical operator. In most languages or formal systems, multiplication for bools is not even defined as an operator. From a CS perspective; what happens with the multiply is an implicit cast from bool to int. The Zen of Python would have us believe that explicit > implicit. Im a believer, but your mileage may vary ;)