# What feature of python makes this expression, with square brackets containing a boolean expression as if it were an index or key, valid?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code looks like it should be invalid, but python 2.7 seems to accept it as valid:

```
sf[(sf['id'] >= 1) & (sf['id'] <= 2)]
```

where `sf` is an `SFrame` object, and `sf['id']` refers to a column of the `SFrame`.

This operation results in an SFrame containing only rows for which the expression in the square brackets is true.

Note: I am asking for a python feature, such as a 'list comprehension', 'generator', etc. rather than a feature of SFrame.

This line of code is used an example in the [documentation for graphlab.SFrame](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.html) in the section titled `Logical Filters`.

Comment: You can have something like: `x = {True: "hello"}` and then have `x[True]`, which will be "hello". What's the problem of boolean key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indexing numpy array with logical operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974640/indexing-numpy-array-with-logical-operator)

Comment: The SFrame does not have a key value pair with boolean values as keys

Comment: @StephenRauch: Thanks for sharing the link, that question does appear to be similar, however it is asking a "how" question related to numpy, while I intended a "what" question about python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Operator overloading.

This was especially confusing as this snippet of code makes use of several overloaded operators: `[ ... ]`, `>=`, `<=`, and `&`.

In this case, it looks like `&`, `<=` and `>=` were overloaded to do a per-element comparison and return a list of 1's and 0's, and `[ ... ]` was overloaded to accept a list of 1's and 0's.

More information about this can be found here: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**lt**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

Answer (score 0):

Python's booleans are simply subclasses of int. True is equivalent to 1, and False to 0.